# Web API OData GeographyPoint Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, spatial

I followed this post on [How to consume SQL Spatial Data with Web API V2.2 for OData V4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2015/01/11/how-to-consume-sql-spatial-data-with-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4/). The same issue is present when using the [OData spatial sample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/2eb16717642a26bb0d3e262d9568eb75426237ea/WebApi/v4/ODataSpatialSample). It works fine when querying spatial data. But when I try to POST a new entity that has a GeographyPoint property, the Web API odata v4 controller ModelState has an InvalidCastException saying Object must implement IConvertible. Has anyone seen this? Which object needs to implement IConvertable? GeographyPoint? That class is in the Microsoft.Spatial NuGet package.

Here is the request sent using olingo odatajs-4.0.0.js

```
{
"requestUri": "/odata/Fields",
"method": "POST",
"data": {
    "Block": "Block B",
    "Location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -2,
            55
        ]
    },
    "Name": "Field B",
    "ClientId": 1
},
"headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json;q=0.9, */*;q=0.1",
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0"
},
"recognizeDates": true,
"callbackParameterName": "$callback",
"formatQueryString": "$format=json",
"enableJsonpCallback": false,
"async": true
}
```

The stack trace of the error in the ModelState is

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.EdmPrimitiveHelpers.ConvertPrimitiveValue(Object value, Type type)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.DeserializationHelpers.SetDeclaredProperty(Object resource, EdmTypeKind propertyKind, String propertyName, Object propertyValue, IEdmProperty edmProperty, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.DeserializationHelpers.ApplyProperty(ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredTypeReference resourceType, Object resource, ODataDeserializerProvider deserializerProvider, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperty(Object entityResource, ODataProperty structuralProperty, IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object entityResource, ODataEntryWithNavigationLinks entryWrapper, IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyEntityProperties(Object entityResource, ODataEntryWithNavigationLinks entryWrapper, IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataEntryWithNavigationLinks entryWrapper, IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.ReadInline(Object item, IEdmTypeReference edmType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataEntityDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
```

The ModelState for a PATCH contains the same error as well